# Write Pandas Dataframe to DBF File?

Tags: python, pandas, shapefile, dbf

I'm working with shapefiles, which have the attribute data stored in a DBF file. I need to manipulate the attributes using Pandas, and write the new DBF data back to disk.

Unfortunately Pandas dataframes don't have a `df.to_dbf` method (whereas R does). I've hunted around but don't seem to see any obvious ways to accomplish this task.

How do I save a pandas dataframe as a DBF file?

Comment: use this:   
http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/     
or convert data frame to csv, then csv to dbf .

Comment: You could also use [this](https://github.com/GeoDaSandbox/sandbox/blob/master/pyGDsandbox/dataIO.py) alternative with  `df2dbf`

Comment: What is a dbf file?  Is it like a .nc file that xarray uses?

Comment: @O.rka the DBF format is an old database format that was popular in the 80's and 90's. It's also part of the shapefile format for storing geographic data, and this format is still popular today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest way to load, manipulate and save the dbf file associated with a shapefile is to use the GeoPandas library. This can load the dbf as a dataframe:

```
gf = gpd.read_file('some_shapefile.shp')
```

You can then manipulate all of the data using standard Pandas commands and export the data back out as a Shapefile (or other geographic file) using the following command:

```
gf.to_file('export.shp')
```

Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using `rpy2` to convert your dataframe to an `R` object then run something like this:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
base.write.dbf(df)
```

Should work seamlessly, I hope!

Comment: interesting! I'll take a look

Comment: unfortunately the last line doesn't work
it causer the error "AttributeError: 'DocumentedSTFunction' object has no attribute 'dbf'"